# Support to upload dictionary of synonyms in azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I was looking for a way to upload a text file of dictionary of synonyms in azure search, the nearest I could find was

1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-search-synonyms-public-preview/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms

I know it is not a good idea to compare products of different companies, but if there exists a way to upload a dictionary of synonyms in azure search like it is supported in elastic search, then it will of great help and might save a lot of time and rework.

Please help me know how to  achieve such thing like uploading the dictionary of the synonym in azure search

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to upload synonyms in Azure Search?

Comment: I am looking for something like this : https://www.paperlesspost.com/blog/teams/setting-up-elasticsearch-synonyms/

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK, a tool like this does not exist. You would have to write something of your own that would parse a text file and upload data in Azure Search using [Synonym Maps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/synonym-map-operations) or use a SDK that consumes this API. Closest tool you could use is [Cerebrata Cerulean](https://www.cerebrata.com) that provides a UI to manage the synonyms. [Disclosure: I am one of the developers on Cerebrata team].

Comment: I'm pretty sure the new Azure SDKs support uploading a synonym map directly from a file. I'll confirm with the engineering team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [.NET SDK for Azure Cognitive Search](https://www.nuget.org/packages/azure.search.documents) has this capability. From [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/samples/Sample02_Service.md#create-a-synonym-map):

```cs
// Create a new SearchIndexClient
Uri endpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SEARCH_ENDPOINT"));
AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SEARCH_API_KEY"));
SearchIndexClient indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(endpoint, credential);

// Create a synonym map from a file containing country names and abbreviations
// using the Solr format with entry on a new line using \n, for example:
// United States of America,US,USA\n
string synonymMapName = "countries";
string synonymMapPath = "countries.txt";

SynonymMap synonyms;
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(synonymMapPath))
{
    synonyms = new SynonymMap(synonymMapName, file);
}

await indexClient.CreateSynonymMapAsync(synonyms);
```

The SDKs for [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/search/azure-search-documents/src/samples/java/com/azure/search/documents/SynonymMapsCreateExample.java), [Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/c4acce962c209a64a2402890f565598228b1cd22/sdk/search/azure-search-documents/samples/sample_synonym_map_operations.py#L32), and [Javascript](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/search/search-documents/samples/javascript/src/synonymMaps/createSynonymMap.js) also support creating synonym maps. The Java SDK accepts a string rather than a file stream, so you'd have to read the file contents yourself. Unfortunately the Python and Javascript SDKs seem to require a list of strings (one for each line of the file), which is something we should improve. I'm following up with the Azure SDK team to make these improvements.